# How do I view my K features with SelectKBest?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection, numpy

I am getting an error for "no attribute columns". Because of this, I can't see the selected K features and can't build plots:

First occurrence of error:

[image]

Second occurrence of error:
I'm also not able to plot the score for each selected feature, I've tried some alternatives but I'm failing:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

get_support() will only return an array, there are no column names in that object. Check this website out for usage:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html

In your code, mask will show an array of True or False values

```
print(mask)
[ True  True  True  True False ... False]
```

If you want the column names,  you can get them from the X_train dataset source.

Also, if you want to plot the scores, you can try something like this.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X_indices = np.arange(X.shape[-1])
...
scores = selector.scores_
scores /= scores.max()
plt.bar(X_indices, scores, width=.2)
```

Output:

[image]